# What happened to Stack Overflow BigQuery?

Tags: bug, status-completed

In [this December 2016 blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/), Stack Overflow announced that they would host Stack Overflow data on BigQuery.

But when I tried to follow the links recently, I couldn't find anything. It turns out that [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow) used to actually look like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170219184650/https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow). So for some reason all the Stack Overflow stuff is *gone*.

What happened to BigQuery here?

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/stack-exchange/stack-overflow?filter=solution-type:dataset&filter=category:social&pli=1

Answer (score 12):

Google changed their site structure and broke all the old links. (Not just the Stack Overflow dataset; all the BigQuery dataset links on the current version of [Google's own public datasets page](https://cloud.google.com/public-datasets/) are broken.)

The new URL is https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/stack-exchange/stack-overflow.

Comment: I really wish Google would start being a little customer focused. They do things like this all the time, or changes APIs. Usually they leave up the old instructions, resulting in a great deal of confusion and wasted time.

Comment: Agreed - there are a lot of dead Google Code links too with basically no apparent attempt to ensure a smooth transitional experience. And I don't mean the content was moved because we all accept that was going to happen - I mean "the content has moved _here_" links were provided that _didn't work_

Comment: In fact considering Google's position in our ecosystem and the amount people seem to love them, they do do some rather obnoxious programmer things!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone here for the help and new links - we've updated the blog post to point to the new location.

Comment: "Go check out our dataset now and poke at it." still has the old URL.